# Gathering data from Access database

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I want to gather some data from some tables of an Access Database, I've found some solutions online, but I haven't found ways to fill a datatable, or dataset, and get each single field properly.

Is it easier for me to get whole tables then get just the info that i want, or should I make a lot of searches in the access DB getting just what i Want each time? Any code snippets for it?

**info:**

- The Access Database is in an ACCDB
  file, with no user or password
- I'm currently using VB.NET, but it
  doesn't matter if you answer in C#

--[EDIT]--
**Sub question**:
 [Connecting to ACCDB format MS-ACCESS database through OLEDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373355/connecting-to-accdb-format-ms-access-database-through-oledb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/ReaddatafromAccessdatabase.htm), you use the [`OleDbDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader(VS.71).aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.OleDb;

class MainClass
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=C:\\Northwind.mdb";

    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders";

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);

    conn.Open();

    OleDbDataReader reader;
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read()) 
    {
      Console.Write(reader.GetString(0).ToString() + " ," );
      Console.Write(reader.GetString(1).ToString() + " ," );
      Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    reader.Close();
    conn.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Still applying, ass soon as I complete it i'll post in here. I'm migrating from other DB, so I have to take each data (connstr, location) from somewhere different. Thank you, by the way =)

Comment: The connection string should include Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 not Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0 (http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007)

Comment: It works. But what if i want to call the field from it's name, not from it's ordinal position in the table ? (without selecting only the field)

Comment: You can't directly. What you can however do is set up an Enum with the correct name->ordinal lookup, but this can get messy.

Comment: Thank you. It actually didn't work with ACCDB, only with .MDB (damn) check question linked in the edit.

Comment: The Jet 4 provider won't work with ACCDB. The answer should be edited to use the ACE provider since it's quite clearly stated in the original question that it's an ACCDB not MDB.

Comment: @KyleRozendo I ask a related Question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475968/read-access-file-accdb-from-stream , would you please check it

Answer (score 1):

If you can fill a DataSet, you have all data (fields) in memory.

- In your Project, use the Data menu to add a DataSource.
- Follow the Wizard. It will create a Typed DataSet for you.
- Drag the new DataSource to a Form. That will show you the code to fill the DS.

Comment: I ask a related Question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475968/read-access-file-accdb-from-stream , would you please check it

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this test program to retrieve data from a DAO database.  This should work for you too.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;


namespace TestReadCfg
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString =
            "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="
        + "c:\\Avtron\\addapt\\Configuration\\testDao.db;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=RainbowTrout;";

        string queryString = "SELECT * from Sections order by Address";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            // Create the Command and Parameter objects.
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                int iRecNbr = 1;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    String sRecord = string.Empty;
                    sRecord = string.Format("Record {0}: ", iRecNbr);
                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        sRecord += string.Format("{0} ", reader[i].ToString());
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(sRecord);
                    iRecNbr++;
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

   }
}
```