# Connecting to ACCDB format MS-ACCESS database through OLEDB

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I've recently made [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365463/gathering-data-from-access-database) about connecting to MS-ACCESS database with .NET in C# or VB.NET. It worked just as intended with MDB, but with accdb it caused an exception in

```
conn.Open();
```

which follows:

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3045472/accdb_fail.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3045472/accdb_fail.png)

Is there another way to do this? My original intention (like stated in the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365463/gathering-data-from-access-database)) is gathering some (actually, a lot of) fields.

Comment: The key point in the answer is that MDB is the Jet 4 format (or earlier formats, e.g., Jet 3.x, and backward-readable in the Jet 4 providers), and ACCDB is the format for the ACE (which is really Jet 4.5 or maybe Jet 5), so you need to use the provider for ACE (which is also able to read/write Jet 4/3.x and probably Jet 2.x).

Comment: It actually worked without any aditional installation, but i'm keeping the link in case it's needed in the client.. And Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use ACE 4 driver, download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en) then use following connection string:

`"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\marcelo.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;"`

Comment: i think yes. or create client-server application with thin clients

Comment: Worked with reader.GetValue(3).ToString() Do you know why it didn't with getstring, even though it was a name?

Comment: @Andrey I ask a related Question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475968/read-access-file-accdb-from-stream , would you please check it