# myReader looking for .mdb and not .accdb

Tags: c#

im currently in my first year on university and c# is relatively new to me.

im currently working on accessing a database through a form for a made up company for one of my assignments and I cant get through an error that returns saying that myReader is trying to find the database called Jap1.mdb even though the database I have it linked to and successfully connecting to called Jap1.accdb.

the connection to the database works fine as I have a datagrid that produces all the information in the database and allows me to search through it so I am unsure as to why it is trying to find Jap1.mdb

this is the code I currently have in my form:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace customer_play
{
    public partial class customersfrm : Form
 {
    OleDbConnection myConn;
    OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter;
    OleDbCommandBuilder cb;
    DataSet ds;

    string myConnection;

    public customersfrm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void customersfrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "jap1.accdb";
        myConn = new OleDbConnection(myConnection);
        myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(" select * Jap1.CustomerDetails ;", myConn);
        cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter);
        myConn.Open();
        ds = new DataSet();
        myConn.Close();

    }

    private void addcustbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string Query = "insert into Jap1.CustomerDetails (myFirstName,mySecondName,myAddress,myCity,myPostCode,myNumber,myEmailAddress,myDateOfBirth,my18Plus) values('" + this.firstnametxt.Text + "','" + this.secondnametxt.Text + "', '" + this.addresstxt.Text + "', '" + this.citytxt.Text + "', '" + this.postcodetxt.Text + "', '" + this.numbertxt.Text + "', '" + this.emailtxt.Text + "', '" + this.dobpicker.Text + "', '" + this.eighteenchkbx.Checked + "') ;";
        OleDbCommand cmdDataBase = new OleDbCommand(Query, myConn);
        OleDbDataReader myReader;

        try {

            myConn.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("New Customer Has Been Added To The Database");

            firstnametxt.Text = "";
            secondnametxt.Text = "";
            addresstxt.Text = "";
            citytxt.Text = "";
            postcodetxt.Text = "";
            numbertxt.Text = "";
            emailtxt.Text = "";
            dobpicker.Text = "";
            eighteenchkbx.Text = "";

            while(myReader.Read()){

            }

        }catch(Exception ex){
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }





    }
}
}
```

any help would be hugely appreciated :)

Comment: Can you post stack trace?

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373355/connecting-to-accdb-format-ms-access-database-through-oledb.  It appears there are driver-specificity issues.  Be sure you have the correct JET driver installed.

Comment: sorry Peuczyriski as I said I am very new to this, how would I go about posting stack trace?

Comment: thanks Don I looked through the post and I came across this issue throughout the week and already tried ensuring I have the correct driver and it is still trying to target a .mdb