# How to load Data from MS Access to Sql server using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a table named 'Abc' in access db which has an extension of '*.accdb'. I wanted to load data nightly from Access table 'Abc' to Sql server database table 'xyz'.
while setting the connection Manager to Access ,I am getting the below error

[image]

can someone help me in finding why i am getting this error? Is there any other way i can transfer data from access to sql server nightly?

thanks in advance

Comment: You could try using the ACE driver instead of the Jet driver. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373355/connecting-to-accdb-format-ms-access-database-through-oledb

Comment: Look for Microsoft Office xx Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider