# VB.NET 2010 to connect to ms access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Can someone show me how to connect vb.net 2010 to ms access database to get the data and display it in vb.net application that I am doing right now. My project is that I am doing dictionary application with vb.net so every time i put new word in search box, I want the vb.net to get the definition from ms access and display it in the application.

And code snippet would be great or tutorial

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365463/gathering-data-from-access-database

Comment: This looks like it has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365463/gathering-data-from-access-database

Answer (score 5):

```
'Grabs data from a table and posts it into a ListView

Dim Table_ As String = "Table1"
Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM " & Table_
Dim MDBConnString_ As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=TestDatabase.mdb;"
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim cnn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(MDBConnString_)

cnn.Open()
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, cnn)
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
da.Fill(ds, Table_)
cnn.Close()

Dim t1 As DataTable = ds.Tables(Table_)
Dim row As DataRow
Dim Item(2) As String

For Each row In t1.Rows
    Item(0) = row(0)
    Item(1) = row(1)
    Dim NextListItem As New ListViewItem(Item)

    ListView1.Items.Add(NextListItem)
Next
```