# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, com, ado

I need help with COM objects, I'm new to this. I'm writing in VB.NET.
I'm encountering an error on the line cat.ActiveConnection = connectionString:

```
"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Arguments have an invalid type, go beyond the allowable range, or conflict with each other.'"
```

```
`Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports ADOX
Imports ADODB
Imports System.Data.Common

Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\access\base.accdb;"

        ' Create an ADOX.Catalog object to work with the database
        Dim cat As New Catalog()
        cat.ActiveConnection = connectionString

        ' Create a new table
        Dim table As New Table()
        table.Name = "Employees"

        ' Create fields for the table
        Dim idField As New ADOX.Column()
        idField.Name = "ID"
        idField.Type = ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger
        idField.ParentCatalog = cat
        table.Columns.Append(idField)

        Dim nameField As New ADOX.Column()
        nameField.Name = "Name"
        nameField.Type = ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar
        nameField.ParentCatalog = cat
        table.Columns.Append(nameField)

        ' Add the table to the database
        cat.Tables.Append(table)

        ' Open a connection to the database
        Dim connection As New Connection()
        connection.Open(connectionString)

        ' Add data to the table
        Dim command As New Command()
        command.ActiveConnection = connection
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Employees (ID, Name) VALUES (1, 'John')"
        command.Execute()

        ' Close the connection
        connection.Close()
    End Sub

End Module

`
```

In Visual Studio, I've added references: Microsoft ActiveX 6.0, Microsoft ADO 6.0. Microsoft Access seems to be 2021 version. .NET Framework is 4.8, and I've also installed AccessDatabaseEngine_X64 and msoledbsql.

I've searched all over Google, but nothing seems to help(

I've tried writing the path as C:/access/base.accdb, changed the location, but the same error persists.

Comment: All questions and answers on the main Stack Overflow site are [required to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/205114).  Please either translate your question or try [ru.so], but be sure to follow their [content guidelines](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure an on-topic question.

Comment: What data type is ID? If it is Autonumber, don't insert value. Although INSERT should work, don't do that - let table generate next number - that's nature of Autonumber. Advise not to use reserved words as names: NAME is a reserved word. Better would be EmpName. Also, ID could end up in multiple tables, rename to something unique, like EmpID.

Comment: Does the connection work at all? Can you pull data with a SELECT query?

Comment: really, I can do nothing, even connect. like I saild: it breaks at "cat.ActiveConnection = connectionString"

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234941/vb-net-2010-to-connect-to-ms-access-database. Your connection looks fine to me.

Comment: It's ok, but I need accdb, moreover, I said that I can't connect even through connection looks good... maybe it's because I can't do normal references... may be anyone can tell me the instructions because I really dunno what to do...

Comment: I'd assume `cat.ActiveConnection` needs a connection object and not a connection string?

Comment: I know you are using accdb. Following links in referenced thread leads to examples using mdb and accdb. Connection string with `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` is same for both. @HardCode has good point.

Comment: How can there be an ActiveConnection if a connection has not been opened? Well, MS docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/catalog-activeconnection-property-example-vb says connection string in place of object should work.

Comment: @June7 "...connection string in place of object should work." Interesting! I've never seen that before in any MS libraries.